# Loading dynamically changing data from an iframe into a div

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a couple of sets of data like so, currently stored inside of an iframe:

```
<ul class = "barcharts">
    <li id = "wind_v">+20kW</li>
    <li id = "battery_v">+20kW</li>
    <li id = "wave_v">+20kW</li>
    <li id = "station_v">+20kW</li>
    <li id = "charge_v">+20kW</li>
    <li id = "solar_v">+20kW</li>
    <li id = "factory_v">+20kW</li>
    <li id = "shops_v">+20kW</li>
    <li id = "house_v">+20kW</li>
</ul>
```

Each of the uls is identical in structure, only thing that changes is the contents of the li. I want to take the values stored, then take just the number out of it, and put that into a function called convert() that converts the numerals into words (25 - two_five), and then change the class of a div to this new value.

```
innerDoc = document.getElementById('values_numbers').contentWindow.document;
```

This gives me access to the values stored inside the div.

```
document.getElementById("wind").className = convert(innerDoc.getElementById("wind_v").innerHTML.match(/\d+/g));
```

I know that the convert function works, its just a simple switch case function, but changing:

```
document.getElementById("wind").className = "two_five";
```

to what I have above is what breaks my page.

My question is: What exactly have I done wrong with the syntax for this not to work like I think it should, or is my logic completely wrong?

Comment: So what is your question now?

Comment: sorry, made it more clear

Comment: it would be easier to answer if we had convert() code, but just quickly, are you sure it shouldn't be:convert(innerDoc.getElementById("wind_v").innerHTML.match(/\d+/g)[0]). Match returns an array, not a string.

Comment: That's actually good to know Julien, cheers! I've actually given up on using iframes, thrown the external values into hidden divs, and my code works now. Still not sure what went wrong, but thanks anyway guys!